# how to use app.compound.finance repayBehalf from contract?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I cant repayBehalf; repayAmount is always 0:
[etherscan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x50395c24d654106383e16fc4d11d1423a32ef868835ee68a7f95ccd92174d6f9#eventlog)

this is the one from website that I did manually: [etherscan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x58cd847c2f9da901021ea5d5e9db875ccfd5bbb178fccbff11aec88f568a1b54#eventlog)

I cant even repayBorrow

```
    symbol ='cETH'
    abi_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/master/networks/kovan-abi.json"
    kovan_json = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/master/networks/kovan.json"
    abi = requests.get(abi_url).json()["Maximillion"]
    contract_address = requests.get(kovan_json).json()['Maximillion']['address']
    compound_token_contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(contract_address))
    nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(ETH_ADDRESS)
    tx = compound_token_contract.functions.repayBehalf( ETH_ADDRESS ).buildTransaction({
        'chainId': 42,
        'gas': 500000,
        'gasPrice': w3.toWei('20', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
        # 'repayAmount ': "-1"
    })
    signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, ETH_ACCT_KEY)
    w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

this is the transaction creator, I am stuck

`contract's .sol` file [here](https://abidocs.dev/contracts/0xf859a1ad94bcf445a406b892ef0d3082f4174088)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by changing `# 'repayAmount ': "-1"` line with `"value": 1`